# SQL Server 2005 and Windows 8.1 - Getting error 1053 when trying to start sqlexpress service

Tags: sql-server

We've been running SQL Server 2005 and Windows 8.1. Today for the first time we can't get `sqlexpress` running in services. It was running fine yesterday.

Getting

> error 1053 - service did not respond to the start or control request.

What steps should I take to troubleshoot this?  Thanks.

Comment: please refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322140 it may help you to fix the issue

Comment: I'm kind of new to sql server troubleshooting. How do i do this?The SQLServerAgent service startup account may not have the correct permissions on the folder that contains SQLAgent.out files.

In this case, make sure that the specified SQLServerAgent service account has full control permissions to the folder in which the SQLAgent.out, SQLAgent.1, SQLAgent.2, and other SQL Server files are located. These files are typically stored in the LOG folder, which is in the SQL Server installation path.

Comment: @runners3431 Feel free to edit your question to further flush out your question it becomes expanded from discussion in comments. Second, why was the service stopped in the first place?

Comment: I'm not really sure, they said it just stopped working today.  I went to take a look and the service was not started

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is not supported on Windows 8.1. Plus question is incomplete because you did not posted the exact error. The error you posted is generic one and to know more about the error go to event viewer and see more details about the error

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server Express does not have SQL Server Agent, so it won't start, no matter how hard you try.

Which service does not start? SQL Server or SQL Server Agent? For SQL Server, please refer to this [great article by Gail Shaw](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/).

Comment: OP did not mentioned about SQL Server agent he is saying SQL Server express services which I guess he means database engine services

Comment: @Shanky the OP mentioned SQL Server Agent in the comments. Care to explain how Gail's article doesn't answer the question according to you?

Comment: His comment was actually for the previous comment posted by Ahmad. If you closely see OP question it says 'for the first time I can't get services running' so he is talking about DB services not agent. Again message posted by him is general message and Gail's article might help instead if looks at event viewer he would find more detailed reason and if he post that answer can be provided